# OptaPlanner: Is there any intrinsic performance benefit in using Bi-/Tri-/QuadConstraintStream over UniConstraintStream with a home grown tuple?

Tags: constraints, optaplanner

Is there any intrinsic performance benefit in using `Bi`-/`Tri`-/`QuadConstraintStream` over `UniConstraintStream` with a home grown tuple?

Is there for example any caching or hashing that OptaPlanner can perform behind the scenes if I use a `BiConstraintStream` and "OptaPlanner tuples" instead of a `UniConstraintStream` with my own tuple?

Comment: 1) Is your home grown tuple natural or artificial in your domain model? 2) Is it a record? 3) Do you only care about today's performance or also about OP's future performance?

Comment: 1) Natural, but only used in the constraint streams. 2) no, but that's an interesting idea for the future! Currently I use Immutables. 3) OP's future performance is of more interest. Honestly, performance is probably secondary to what's considered "OptaPlanner idiomatic" code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is hard to say with confidence; performance questions in Java are best answered with benchmarks. In the absence of a specific problem to benchmark, I'm going to use some common sense to perhaps approximate the correct answer.

There are really only two cases I can think of where stream cardinality can be reduced:

- `map(...)` building block
- or `groupBy(...)`.

There are also two cases where stream cardinality can be increased:

- `join(...)`,
- and `groupBy(...)`.

(Side note: In the future, `map(...)` will probably be overloaded to also allow cardinality increases.)

Assuming you only ever decrease cardinality after you've done your joins, I don't think there would be a performance penalty for a one-time cardinality decrease at the end of the stream. If, on the other hand, you had a mix of cardinality decreasing and increasing operations, the perpetual creation and destruction of your custom tuple instances could considerably increase GC pressure and therefore give a performance penalty.

But even in the most simple case of no cardinality increases at all, I think that re-mapping to a single tuple still is a bad idea for several reasons:

- The GC pressure argument doesn't really go away. Your tuple instances are still created and then thrown away, as they seem to be nothing but carrier objects.
- Custom tuple instances also bring indirection. What used to be accessed as variable `x` will now be accessed as instance field `tuple.x` or via a method call `tuple.getX()`. This overhead is very small, but it is measurable if the operation is performed often enough.
- I think that this indirection would also result in a code that is worse to read. But that may be just my personal preference.

Finally, and perhaps most importantly, what would even be the point of introducing this middleman data carrier? `map(...)` only exists so that a theoretical use case for penta-streams can be enabled via these carrier objects; other than that, this pattern should be entirely unnecessary. (And we have not yet seen anyone actually requiring penta streams.)

Comment: "In the future, map(...) will probably be overloaded to also allow cardinality increases" - I think that will be useful! You make some interesting points. It could very well be that I'm simply not familiar enough with the constraints API (especially all the `groupBy` variants). I figured it's slightly more readable to have named fields ("records") than tuples but I'm not sure any more. The constraints API also only allows one to flatten the last element in the tuple. Having a custom uni-constraint-objekt allows one to flatten on any field. Maybe one can rearrange a tuple with a `groupBy`.. 

Comment: Many things are possible with grouping and flattening. But those operations have a performance cost; I would only use them if I had a problem to solve, not for "cosmetic" reasons.

Comment: Right, but if "the problem to solve" is to flatten a tuple, then it must be in the last position of the tuple, right? So then there's the question of, should I use an extra `groupBy` to rearrange the tuple so that the element to flatten comes last, or should I go for a custom class, in which case all fields (or "all elements of the tuple") is available in the last (and only) position.

Comment: I don't see how you could use `groupBy` to rearrange the tuple while maintaining the original contents; so if that is your requirement, going with your custom class seems like the only option. That said, I find it curious that doing any of this is easier than making sure the thing to flatten is the last element in the original tuple.

Comment: Hmm.. I was thinking of `.groupBy((a, b) -> b, (a, b) -> a)`, but that obviously assumes uniqueness of the elements, so ignore that part. Quite clear by now that I'm still new to this ;-D

Answer (score 2):

Everything Lukas said. Benchmarks with JFC/JMC allocation profiles for a trustworthy answer. My guesstimate:

No, currently, there probably is no intrinsic benefit performance wise over a home grown tuple. And if there is any, it's probably a rounding error. That might or might not change in future versions.

In fact, if your using records for your home grown tuples, those might be even faster (OptaPlanner can't do that until it's minimum java 17).

It's ok to use a home grown tuple with a UniStream if you prefer that over BiStream without it.

But you might loose ease-of-use, I suspect. That's one of the reasons Bi, Tri, Quad streams etc were designed: easier expressiveness, so easier to read, so easier for maintenance (especially when the business requirements change).

Comment: Also note: the devil is in the details. How/when you construct the home grown tuple can easily kill your performance. For example, if it mimics a join and kills hashing and/or incremental calculation. Home grown tuples that are part of the domain input problem are generally ok.

Comment: What I've done is that I've use Immutables and basically done something like `.groupBy(MyImmutable::of, ...)` to get a "complex" groupBy (i.e. use Immutables-generated equals based on all fields). I found it fairly elegant and working with uni-stream of something with named fields was slightly easier to grasp for me, at least when I didn't fully understand all the `groupBy` overloads.

Comment: That's fine. I would estimate it makes no noticeable performance difference, regardless if it's faster or slower.

Comment: They groupBy overloads mixing mappingKeys and collectors can make the code harder to read. Maybe we should support something like `groupBy(MapKeySet.of(key1, key2),CollectorSet.of(collector1, collector2)) returns QuadStream` some day. But that would create even more overloaded methods... so maybe not :)

Comment: I would understand the idea behind such overload :-) It takes some time to understand the flexibility of the `groupBy` "building block". The constraint stream API is conceptually quite similar to SQL, but `groupBy` seems much more versatile than SQL's `GROUP BY`. If I understand it correctly, `groupBy` can rearrange the tuple and the aggregation operations are baked in to it as opposed to SQL's `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Wrt. the overload - we don't have it for group keys, but for collectors, we actually do have a composition. Check out `ConstraintCollectors.compose(...)`.

Comment: Definitely going to read up on that. Thanks.